# Vue.js - как правильно перенести html с функцией в component

Tags: html, vue.js

Всем привет. 
Есть один код, который работает. По кнопке картинка показывается/прячется.

```js
var pageSettings = new Vue({
    el: '#page',
    data: {
        showImg: true
    }
 });
```

```html
<div id="page">
<button @click="showImg = !showImg">showImg</button>
<img v-if="showImg" src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?resize=640%2C426">
</div>
```

[Код в JSfiddle 1.](http://jsfiddle.net/x8wo7mr9/3/)

Но есть потребность перенесения кнопки в компонент.
Однако, при вызове из него, она не работает.

[Код в JSfiddle 2.](http://jsfiddle.net/bsewpv71/1/)

Не могу понять, как сделать правильно. Прошу подсказать. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Все таки, сделал. Все оказалось не так сложно. Однако, рекомендуется делать подобные вещи через $emit](https://jsfiddle.net/VeVeO/a0cmny4v/1/)

```js
Vue.component('showimgbutton', {
 template: '<button @click="togglePic">showImg</button>',
  methods: {
        togglePic: function() {
            page.showImg = !page.showImg;
        },
    }
});

var page = new Vue({
    el: '#page',
    data: {
        showImg: true
    }
 });
```

```html
<div id="page">
<showimgbutton></showimgbutton>
<img v-if="showImg" src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?resize=640%2C426">
</div>
```